# The Wright brothers are the inventors of "aircraft"? "aircrafts"? "the aircraft"? "the aircrafts"?

Tags: definite-article, singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

Which sentence would be most appropriate?

- The Wright brothers are the inventors of aircraft.
- The Wright brothers are the inventors of an aircraft.
- The Wright brothers are the inventors of aircrafts?
- The Wright brothers are the inventors of the aircraft?
- The Wright brothers are the inventors of the aircrafts?

I am not mentioning a particular aircraft, but the invention.

```
How about "airplane"?

 - The Wright brothers are the inventors of airplane.
   
 - The Wright brothers are the inventors of an airplane.
   
 - The Wright brothers are the inventors of airplanes?
   
 - The Wright brothers are the inventors of the airplane?
   
 - The Wright brothers are the inventors of the airplanes?

Which one should be used?
```

Comment: Not sure invention is the right word. They built an airplane.

Comment: ↑ They made the first powered, controlled flight. They did not invent the aeroplane.

Comment: I'm asking about English grammar.  I don't need detailed information about aircraft.

Comment: aircraft is a generic term and an uncountable noun and you are misusing it. Sorry. We don't say aircraft were invented. We say The airplane was invented by x.

Answer (score 2):

*Technically*, the Wright brothers invented the aeroplane (or airplane in US English).  *Aircraft* such as the Giffard dirigible had existed previously.

I'd probably use the past tense and use "invent" as the main verb, as it is shorter.

And article "the" is used to mean "the entire category of 'airplanes'", and not a particular instance of one.

> The Wright brothers invented the airplane.

Answer (score -1):

ther first sentence:

> The Wright brothers are the inventors of aircraft.

is grammatically valid and natural. Whether it is accurate might be debated.

When "aircraft" is used to mean the general concept of machines that fly. no article is used. The word "aircraft" is plural as well as singular, so "aircrafts" is not used in any case. It is not a valid English word.